# Setting up inferior-lisp for clojure repl

Tags: emacs, clojure

I'm trying to adding inferior-lisp support for clojure. I've read several articles how to do it and it looks so easy, just do something like this:

```
M-x set-variable inferior-lisp-program "lein repl"
```

and then I hit

```
C-c C-z
```

And it does the job, which is the repl is on. But when I type something e.g. `(def foo "bar")` and hit enter, the repl just idle. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Can't reproduce: `run-lisp` works as intended for me. Are you aware of `cider`?

Comment: Same here. You should really be using `cider`, though.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try `cider`.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this [blog](http://martintrojer.github.io/clojure/2014/10/02/clojure-and-emacs-without-cider/) which shows a way to not using cider.